# Append elements of a list to another list multiple times without for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

I want to add the elements of a list to an empty list several times. Because of the large number of duplication, I would like to do it without for loop. 
example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = []
duplicationNumber = 3
```

output:

```
b = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is obtainable by working through a tutorial or two on lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b + a*duplicationNumber` will do it. Multiplying a list by an integer duplicates the list that many times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a*3

Output is:
b = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]